# Is "increasingly" a grammar mistake in "She turned increasingly to radical diets to lose weight"?

Tags: grammar

I wonder if this is a grammar mistake:

> She turned increasingly to radical diets to lose weight.

Why use *increasingly*?

Comment: We use *increasingly* to suggest a progressive trend toward something. In other words, over time this person either tried more and more radical diets, or increased her reliance on them.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Please edit to say a bit more about why you're not sure about the usage. Is it the choice of word, or the use of an adverb, or the way it's inserted into the verb phrase?